# Python's Subprocess management

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

The [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) has both a `returncode` and a `stderr` value when in the tuple returned by `.communicate()`.  If there is a value assigned to `stderr`, is this classed as the program successfully run and finished (and hence `returncode` will be 0) or not (and then the value of `returncode` will be greater than 0)?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'd be really interested why 2 people think that 'This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful'

Comment: Frustrating when people won't face up to their actions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stderr` refers to the standard error stream of the process, as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29

You can write messages to that for debug purposes, and still have an exit code of zero.

Answer (score -1):

Popen.**communicate** will return a tuple containing the data that was writte to *stdout* and *stderr* (or None for each value if nothing was written).

After communicate returns you can inspect the **returncode** attribute on your Popen instance to get the exit status of the process, if this differs from 0 it is generally an indication that an error occurred.

Comment: Yes - I understand this.  I didn't know if the exit code *had* to be >0 if `stderr` was not null

Comment: No, the returncode does not have to be >0 of stderr is not None, any process can decide to write something to stderr.